# How can I run this tcp command in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, nc

I want to run this command in Ubuntu:

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:50010 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN <pid>/java
```

but `tcp` is not recognized in Ubuntu. What could be an alternative for this?

Comment: Why do you want to run that command?   As noted above, this is *output* from another command, and includes `java` as the only executable part of it. Are you wanting to write a java program that listens on port 50010? Please spell out your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find solution using this guide.

Use `netstat` command

1. Listing all the LISTENING Ports of TCP and UDP connections

   Listing all ports (both TCP and UDP) using `netstat -a` option.
2. Listing TCP Ports connections

   Listing only TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) port connections using 
   `netstat -at`.

Link:

[20 Netstat Commands for Linux Network Management](https://www.tecmint.com/20-netstat-commands-for-linux-network-management/)